# How to get an element from tuple defined as type synonym in haskell

Tags: haskell, tuples, getter

I'm in a situation where I use a tuple defined as type synonym, so I can't really use record structure.
Is there a way to get these elements?

To be more specific here is what I mean:

```
 type Movie  = (Title, Regisseur, MainActors, ReleaseDate, Genre, SalesPrice)  

 type Title = String

 type SalesPrice = Int   

 etc
```

How can I get only `Title` and `ReleaseDate` for an example. Besides than defining a getter function for every position in the tuple of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One other option is to import the package `Control.Lens`.

```
>>> import Control.Lens
>>> let movie = ( "The Terminator"
                , "James Cameron"
                , ["Arnold Schwartzenegger", "Michael Biehn"]
                , 1984
                ,"Science Fiction"
                , 19.99)
>>> movie ^. _1
"The Terminator"
>>> movie ^. _4
1984
```

I wouldn't recommend that you do this though. Use record syntax instead.

```
data Movie = Movie
           { title       :: String
           , director    :: String
           , mainActors  :: [String]
           , releaseDate :: Int
           , genre       :: String
           , price       :: Double
           } deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)
```

Now you can do

```
>>> let movie = Movie "The Terminator" "James Cameron"
                      ["Arnold Schwartzenegger", " Michael Biehn"]
                      1984 "Science Fiction" 19.99
>>> title movie
"The Terminator"
>>> releaseDate movie
1984
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to define (or derive) a getter for every component of the tuple.

E.g.

```
title :: Movie -> Title
title (t,_,_,_,_,_,_) = t
```

Such accessors can be made simpler by using records instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use uniplate to get all tuple elements of a specific type using uniplate. Note that uniplate will treat different type synonyms as if they are the same.

```
import Data.Generics.Uniplate.Data
.
.
.
let [title] = childrenBi movie
```

If you want something that differentiates between fields, it might be better to use record syntax: [Haskell record syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367167/haskell-record-syntax)

Comment: A nice suggestion at any rate. — Record syntax is _definitely_ preferrable here, IMO.